# Upsert list<SObject> with external id

Tags: list, sobject, upsert

I want to upsert a list of generic sobject with the external id field. This list of generic sobject contains records from different sobjects, where the sobject type will be unknown and will be determined only at run time.

I understand that I need to split this list into different list of specific sobject and then perform the upsert.

Just not sure how to create those different list of sobject from one list of generic sobject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the `instanceof` operator to determine the SObjectType.
If you know which SObjectTypes to expect, you could do something like

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();
// ... and so on
for(SObject record : mySObjects) {
    if(record instanceof Account) {
        accounts.add((Account)record);
    } else if(record instanceof Opportunity) {
        opportunities.add((Opportunity)record);
    } // else if etc
}
upsert accounts MyExternalIdField__c;
upsert opportunities AlsoAnExternalIdField__c;
// etc
```

If you want a more generic approach, you could store everything in a Map<SObjectType, List> and then upsert from there:

```
Map<SObjectType, List<SObject>> recordsByType = new Map<SObjectType, List<SObject>>();
// populate map
for(SObject record : mySObjects) {
    SObjectType sObjectType = record.getSObjectType();
    if(!recordsByType.containsKey(sObjectType)) {
        recordsByType.put(sObjectType, new List<SObject>());
    } 
    recordsByType.get(sObjectType).add(record);
}

// loop through types and upsert
for(SObjectType sObjectType : recordsByType.keySet()) {
    List<SObject> records = recordsByType.get(sObjectType);
    SObjectField externalIdField = sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('My_External_Id__c');
    Database.upsert(records, externalIdField, true);
}
```

Note that for this to work the name of the external ID field needs to be exactly the same across all objects. If not, you have to implement additional logic to determine which field you want to use as external ID.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I want to keep the SObject types also dynamic. I can get the list of sobject types from a custom metadata or a custom label. Is it possible to initialize the list of sobject dynamically?

Comment: Basically creating a list of sobject, given the api name of the sobject is retrieved from a custom label or custom metadata.

Comment: `SObject` is a dynamic type, so you can just create a `List<SObject>`, and add new records created via `sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(ObjectName).newSObject() ;`

Comment: @manjit5190 - I am actually trying to split the original list of sobject into multiple lists of sobject. I already have the combined list.

Comment: You should simply have a Map<String, List<SObject>> where key is the object API name.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to include a generic approach. Note that in that case you are need a uniform approach to determine the external ID field, for now I've assumed the API name of that field is equal across objects

Comment: @manjit5190 Thanks. this actually helps in moving further for creating the separate lists. Now i'm stuck at declaring the external field for upserting these different lists. I have the following - 

Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjType).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName);

I'm wondering if there is a better way to avoid the globaldescribe

Comment: @Steven.B This is perfect. sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('My_External_Id__c'); alongwith the map approach recommended by manjit5190 resolves my problem.